# Execute PowerShell from C# in non-interactive mode

Tags: c#, powershell

I am running some PowerShell scripts in C# using the System.Management.Automation namespace.
This works perfectly, except when I invoke the script, I very briefly see a command window flash onto the screen and then disappear. This behavior is not acceptable in my application.

I can avoid this behavior by launching a new Process and setting CreateNoWindow=true, however I would really prefer to use the managed PowerShell library. How can I do this in a non-interactive way that does't flash on the screen?

An example of some PowerShell that causes the window flash:

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddCommand(@"Get-WindowsUpdateLog");
    ps.AddParameter(@"-LogPath", @"C:\WindowsUpdate.Log");
    var psOutput = ps.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: i think you need a custom runspace https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn569260(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I took a look at the custom runspace and initial session state but couldn't find anything pertaining to UI interactivity.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the flash you're seeing is because the `Get-WindowsUpdateLog` function internally calls `tracerpt.exe` which is a console app. Running a console app from a GUI results in a flash. (You'll see the same flash if you run `GetWindowsUpdateLog` from the ISE.) Unfortunately there isn't much you can do about it. You could modify you Win32 app to allocate a console handle at startup controlling *when* you see the flash but you'll still see it.